# QualifierValues.MapChanged Crashes App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm using the `ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.QualifierValues.MapChanged` event to detect language changes while my app is running. This works fine, but I get a warning:

> 'ResourceManager.DefaultContext.get' is obsolete: 'DefaultContext may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView.

I switch my app to `ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().QualifierValues.MapChanged` instead but the app now crashes when starting up. I don't get any exception breaks and I get a separate Visual Studio window that pops up to debug and the only option is a new instance of Visual Studio.

What is wrong and how do I fix this?

Failing code example:

```
// App.xaml.cs

protected async override Task OnInitializeAsync( IActivatedEventArgs args )
{
    // Doesn't work. Yes this is in an async method...
    ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValuesMapChanged;

    // But this is the next line and works fine.
    Dispatcher.Initialize();

    // This works just fine.
    ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValuesMapChanged;

    // So does this.
    ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValuesMapChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in a sample project I created, it works!! 
I don't know exactly why you face this error.. but you could try this:

```
try {

 var resourceContext = ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
 resourceContext.QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValuesMapChanged;
}
catch(Exception ex){ 
ex.Handled = true;
Debug.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Maybe we catch the exception, because now we'll just try things without making sure what if it'll work or not.

Comment: That callback never happens. The app crashes immediately.

Comment: Answer updated, can't you debug it or get any error message?
Please try to subscribe to the event by using Dispatcher.. it make sense as you call the GetForCurrentView()

Comment: The event subscription is already on the UI thread, so there is no point in running it through the dispatcher. It happens in `App.xaml.cs` when starting. Also, the only way it would blow up is if it was trying to access something in the UI from a non-UI thread.

Comment: There is no debugging information which I stated in my question. `I don't get any exception breaks and I get a separate Visual Studio window that pops up to debug and the only option is a new instance of Visual Studio.`

Comment: Can you please share the code with me so I can understand it in a clear way?
I'm really interested in this..

Comment: It passes that line just fine, but when the page loads, the app crashes. I have the `Exception Settings` set to break when anything is thrown, and that's not catching anything. I get a separate window that comes up that asks if I want to debug and the only option it gives me is a new instance of visual studio (not the running one). Doing that doesn't give me any information either.